# How to put each rows in json index?

Tags: php, json, api, rest

Sorry for the misleading title, anyway I have this line of code:

```
$results = $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM user");
if(count($results) > 0)
{
     return '{"user": ' . json_encode($results) . '}';
}
return http_response_code(204);
```

The code above allow me to get a list of users, actually I get this result:

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "id": "R89d",
      "description": "admin",
      "created": "2016-03-20 20:45:09",
      "lastUpdate": "2016-03-20 20:45:09"
    },
    {
      "id": "RB01",
      "description": "normal",
      "created": null,
      "lastUpdate": "2016-03-22 10:54:48"
    },
    {
      "id": "RT40",
      "description": "tester",
      "created": null,
      "lastUpdate": null
    }
  ]
}
```

but I need to get this result instead:

```
{
"user": [
    {
      "details":{
      "id": "R89d",
      "description": "admin",
      "created": "2016-03-20 20:45:09",
      "lastUpdate": "2016-03-20 20:45:09"
      }
    },
    {
      "details":{
      "id": "RB01",
      "description": "normal",
      "created": null,
      "lastUpdate": "2016-03-22 10:54:48"
      }
    },
    {
     "details":{
      "id": "RT40",
      "description": "tester",
      "created": null,
      "lastUpdate": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How you can see each user is inside the index `details`. How can I how can I do this quickly and easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to wrap the data in a details object. Like so:

```
<?php

$results = $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM user");
if(count($results) > 0)
{
    $results = array_map(function($u) { return ['details' => $u]; }, $results);
    return '{"user": ' . json_encode($results) . '}';
}
return http_response_code(204);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's like saying:

```
$makes = array( 'car' => 'ford', 'car' => 'citron', 'car' => $anotherCar );
```

You cannot get the value of `$makes['car']`.

So you can, however, store a temp array to use and append details as an array like so:

```
$temp = array();
if(count($results) > 0)
{
     foreach ($results as $v)
     {
         array_push($temp, $v);
     }
     return '{"user": ' . json_encode($temp) . '}';
}
```

But `details` would be replaced with `0,1,2 [...]`.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple approch could be using foreach...

```
$results = $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM user");
if(count($results) > 0)
{
   $resultnew = array();
   foreach($results as $result)
   {
     $resultnew['details'][] = $result;
   }
    return '{"user": ' . json_encode($resultnew) . '}';
}
return http_response_code(204);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below script.

```
    $results = $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM user");
    $a = json_decode($results,true);

    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
         $b[]['details'] = $value;
    }


    $new_result = json_encode($b);

   if(count($results) > 0)
   {
      return '{"user": ' . $new_result . '}';
    }
 return http_response_code(204);
```